# rect.set the hover area is not updated

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How can I use the `object.set({})` and then have hover area update.

For example when I move a rect to the left, visually the rect has moved but the hover area is still based on the previous left position.

Do I need to do an additional render?

I figured `canvas.renderAll()` would be enough

Here is a demo

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(document.getElementById("myCanvas"));

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: "red",
  left: 25,
  top: 25
});

canvas.add(rect);

const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  rect.set({ left: 125 });
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <style>
  canvas {
   border: 1px solid black;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="app"></div>
 <button id="btn">move left</button>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" ></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/rlo3ojwvp4

Comment: You need to call `rect.setCoords()`

Comment: don't see any `hover` what do you want/mean exactly?

Comment: @JSmith By hover I mean moving your cursor over the previous position

Comment: @Lonelydatum I'm sorry but I'm not sure ti understan well, your code looks just fine. I on't really get the mouse hover on last position thing can you try explain it to me in other words. thx in advance

Comment: @Durga solution worked. Here is a video of what I mean. https://www.useloom.com/share/f87f1970bf46478f9f6b89877b99b962

Comment: @Lonelydatum oh amazing thanks for the video.

Comment: See here for a list of actions that require calling `.setCoords()` https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/When-to-call-setCoords

Answer (score 1):

You need to set coordinates after move,check [When-to-call-setCoords](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/When-to-call-setCoords)

***DEMO***

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(document.getElementById("myCanvas"));

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: "red",
  left: 25,
  top: 25
});

canvas.add(rect);

const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  rect.set({ left: 125 });
  rect.setCoords();
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <style>
  canvas {
   border: 1px solid black;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="app"></div>
 <button id="btn">move left</button>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" ></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```